# Php to create multiple csv(s) files from one mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, export-to-csv

UPDATE #1
I have one php file with multiple queries that create multiple csv files.
I want to combine the queries.

My mysql `table` has 5 columns: ID, currency, rate, date, temptime

Create the table `table` and insert some records

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `table` ( `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , `currency` VARCHAR(254) NOT NULL , `rate` FLOAT NOT NULL , `date` VARCHAR(254) NOT NULL , `temptime` DATE NOT NULL , PRIMARY KEY (`id`), UNIQUE `UNIQUE` (`currency`, `temptime`)) ENGINE = MyISAM;

INSERT INTO `table` 
(currency, rate, date, temptime)
VALUES 
('USD', '1.232', '1521212400', '2018-03-16'),
('USD', '1.258', '1521126000', '2018-03-15'),
('JPY', '133.82', '1521212400', '2018-03-16'),
('JPY', '131.88', '1521126000', '2018-03-15'),
('EUR', '1.99', '1521212400', '2018-03-16'),
('EUR', '1.85', '1521126000', '2018-03-15'),
('BRL', '1.6654', '1521212400', '2018-03-16'),
('BRL', '1.5498', '1521126000', '2018-03-15'),
('ZAR', '1.99654', '1521212400', '2018-03-16'),
('ZAR', '2.0198', '1521126000', '2018-03-15'),
('RUB', '19.9654', '1521212400', '2018-03-16'),
('RUB', '20.0198', '1521126000', '2018-03-15');
```

These are the 2 queries I want to combine for the column "currency"  USD and  EUR :

```
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT temptime, rate FROM `table` WHERE currency='USD' ORDER BY date asc"); 
if (!$result) die('Couldn\'t fetch records'); 
$num_fields = mysql_num_fields($result); 
$headers = array(); 
for ($i = 0; $i < $num_fields; $i++) 
{     
       $headers[] = mysql_field_name($result , $i); 
} 
$fp = fopen('csv/USD.csv', 'w'); 


if ($fp && $result) 
{     
       fputcsv($fp, $headers); 
       while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) 
       {
          fputcsv($fp, array_values($row)); 
       }
} 

$result = mysql_query("SELECT temptime, rate FROM `table` WHERE currency='EUR' ORDER BY date asc"); 
if (!$result) die('Couldn\'t fetch records'); 
$num_fields = mysql_num_fields($result); 
$headers = array(); 
for ($i = 0; $i < $num_fields; $i++) 
{     
       $headers[] = mysql_field_name($result , $i); 
} 
$fp = fopen('csv/EUR.csv', 'w'); 


if ($fp && $result) 
{     
       fputcsv($fp, $headers); 
       while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) 
       {
          fputcsv($fp, array_values($row)); 
       }
}
```

Thank you

Comment: **Warning**: Do note use [mysql_](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) functions. They are deprecated since PHP 5.5 and entirely removed in PHP 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the currency field in each row to decide which file to write to, I've used an array of file handles so rather than having any conditions around which file, you just use the currency as the index to the file handle...

```
// Create an array of files, each associated with currency
$fp = array( 'EUR' => fopen('csv/EUR.csv', 'w'),
        'USD' => fopen('csv/USD.csv', 'w'));

$result = mysql_query("SELECT currency, temptime, rate FROM `table` ORDER BY date asc");
if (!$result) die("Couldn't fetch records");
$num_fields = mysql_num_fields($result);
$headers = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < $num_fields; $i++)
{
    $headers[] = mysql_field_name($result , $i);
}
// Write out headers to each file.
foreach ( $fp as $output )  {
    fputcsv($output, $headers);
}

while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))     {
    // Use first field to decide which file to write to.
    $currency = array_shift($row);
    fputcsv($fp[$currency], $row);
}
// Close all of the files.
foreach ( $fp as $output )  {
    fclose($output);
}
```

As I don't have your database, I can't test this, but if you have any problems, then let me know.

Comment: Thanks, it doesn't work, maybe there is something missing in WHERE... 
This the table:

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `table` ( `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , `currency` VARCHAR(254) NOT NULL , `rate` FLOAT NOT NULL , `date` VARCHAR(254) NOT NULL , `temptime` DATE NOT NULL , PRIMARY KEY (`id`), UNIQUE `UNIQUE` (`currency`, `temptime`)) ENGINE = MyISAM;

Comment: Sorry - I'd taken the condition out and left the WHERE in, removed it in the code,can you try again.

Comment: Hi, it writes the csv(s), but gives this warning:
`Warning: fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, array given in /home/curr/public_html/1.php on line 41`

Line 41:
`    fclose($fp);`

Comment: I have updated the question with some lines to create the table and insert some records.

Comment: Again - appologies, should be `fclose($output);`

Comment: Thanks Nigel,
now it's ok if I ask for all records in the table for column "currency", but if select only some currency (ex. EUR and USD) while there are EUR, USD and RUB, it gives me these warnings (repeated twice) for the currency I don't aks for:

`Notice: Undefined index: RUB in /home/curr/public_html/1.php on line 40

Warning: fputcsv() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in /home/curr/public_html/1.php on line 40`


line 40 = fputcsv($fp[$currency], $row);

Comment: If you don't need them at all you can add back ` WHERE currency IN ('USD', 'EUR' )` with all the ones you want.

Answer (score 0):

Consider also using no loops and exporting to CSV directly from MySQL with its [`SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select-into.html) (the complement of `LOAD DATA INFILE`).

Specifically, execute both action queries separately below in PHP (be sure to escape quotes). While not combined, this process should be a faster read/write IO process than multiple loops. Plus, you can swap the app layer (i.e., use Python, Java) without changing csv export code!

```sql
SELECT temptime, rate 
INTO OUTFILE '/path/to/csv/USD.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
FROM `table` 
WHERE currency='USD' 
ORDER BY `date` asc;

SELECT temptime, rate 
INTO OUTFILE '/path/to/csv/EUR.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
FROM `table` 
WHERE currency='EUR' 
ORDER BY `date` asc;
```

And for one call, placed both in MySQL stored procedure:

```sql
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS export_csv$$

CREATE PROCEDURE export_csv
BEGIN
    -- SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE COMMANDS
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Then in PHP run it with a one-liner (using `mysqli` API):

```php
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "CALL export_csv")
```

---

Do note: headers are not passed with above commands. To resolve adjust query with a union requiring type conversion. And CSVs do not store types or unicodes metadata to have issue here.

```sql
SELECT 'temptime' as col1, 'rate' as col2
UNION ALL
SELECT CAST(temptime, CHAR(10) as col1, 
       CAST(ROUND(rate,4) AS CHAR(3)) as col2
INTO OUTFILE '/path/to/csv/USD.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
FROM `table` 
WHERE currency='USD' ;
```